# why do I have duplicates for every post with the same collection name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, models

Hi I have a posts model and a collections model, joined together by a collectionship model. When a user makes a post he adds the post to a collection, such as 'music'. However, when I list all the user's collections there are multiple 'music' entries for each post made instead of just 1. 
I'm grabbing the collections with @collections = @user.posts.map(&:collections).flatten, if I add a .uniq on the end get no duplicates (@collections = @user.posts.map(&:collections).flatten.uniq) But could someone explain why I'd have to do this??? Thanks a lot.

## UsersController

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
    @posts = @user.posts.paginate(:per_page => "10",:page => params[:page])
    @title = @user.name
    @collections = @user.posts.map(&:collections).flatten
  end
```

## views/users/show.html.erb

```
 <h1>Collections</h1>

  <% @collections.each do |collection| %>
    <%= link_to collection.name, user_collection_posts_path(@user, link_name(collection)) %><br />
  <% end %>
```

## collection model

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, CollectionUploader
  attr_accessible :name, :image, :user_id
  has_many :collectionships
  has_many :users, :through => :posts
  has_many :posts, :through => :collectionships
end
```

## collectionship model

```
class Collectionship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :collection
  has_one :user, :through => :post
  attr_accessible :post_id, :collection_id
end
```

## post model

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :collectionships
  has_many :collections, :through => :collectionships
```

## user mdoel

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :collections, :through => :posts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the line that's causing it.  Here's my take on why you're seeing what you do (just an expansion of each step of evaluation of that line):

```
@user.posts #=>
[
    <Post1:
        id: 1492
        collections: ['history', 'spain']
    >,
    <Post2:
        id: 1912
        collections: ['history', 'shipwrecks']
    >
]

@user.posts.map(&:collections) #=>
[
    ['history', 'spain'],
    ['history', 'shipwrecks']
]

@user.posts.map(&:collections).flatten #=>
[
    'history',
    'spain',
    'history',
    'shipwrecks'
]
```

So you can see that each for each post, `post.collections` returns *all* the collections that post is in (as it should).  And the `flatten` method doesn't care if there are duplicates or not - it just cares about returning a single, 1-D array.  So those duplicates survive throughout the whole operation, unless you call `uniq` on the final product.

I believe there's an ActiveRecord way to avoid this as well:  If a User `has_many :collections`, then `@user.collections` shouldn't have any duplicates.  Might be an ugly AR macro, though, with so many levels of inheritance.

Anyway, hope that helps!